# grails fail to compile, error Failed to resolve dependencies

Tags: grails

i installed plugin jasper, after that i m not able to compile my project, it pops up following error and i cant even uninstall the plugin, so any sugesstion to solve this ?

```
|Loading Grails 2.2.1
   |Configuring classpath
   :: problems summary ::
   :::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.olap4j#olap4j;0.9.7.309-JS-3
   Error |
   Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

   - org.olap4j:olap4j:0.9.7.309-JS-3
```

Comment: which plugin exactly?  `compile ":jasper:1.11.0"`? version?

Comment: hi, i downloaded the olap4j.jar and add  runtime "org.olap4j:olap4j:0.9.7.309-JS-3" in dependencies, then the problem solved, the application is running ok now,,,but the jsper plugin still not work..

Comment: hi, i downloaded the olap4j.jar and add  runtime "org.olap4j:olap4j:0.9.7.309-JS-3" in dependencies, then the problem solved, the application is running ok now,,,but the jsper plugin still not work..

Comment: I also encounted same error.... did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add this one in repositories for current time:

```
mavenRepo("https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add repository below to your build script

```
maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
```

or

```
maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
```

in my case, I could solve this issue. (solve dependency)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add repository in buildConfig.groovy file

```
repositories {
    mavenRepo "http://dev.mapfish.org/maven/repository/"
}
```